# Parse,User.signUp error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

The code below creates a user in Parse but always returns and error with meaningless error info.

```
    var user = new Parse.User();

    user.set("username", "jaskaye17");    // in my app, email==username
    user.set("password", "1234");
    user.set("email", "exmaple@gmail.com");

    user.signUp(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            alert('Successfully created user' + user);
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Error message " + error.message + '; Error code ' + error.code);
        }
    });
```

1. The user is create in the user table but,
2. `user.signUp` returns an error
3. The error message is nonsensical

   ```
   e.Error
   code: -1
   message: ""
   __proto__: Object
   ```

What is code: `-1` and why is message `""`. Shouldn't there be more information about what the error is?

Comment: This [link](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-sdk-returning-parseerror-code-1-message) might be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using IE, try use firefox or chrome to see the actual message